# Ubuntu maverick 10.10 fails to shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, process

Occasionally, perhaps after one or two days since the last reboot, I find that ubuntu (maverick 10.10) will not shutdown.  Rather than kill the power, what is the recommended procedure to deal with this?  Does the disk icon for a mounted disk (Windows 7) impede shutdown?  In a way, this question might be about how to recognize process names when we have no guarantee over the quality of descriptive names.  Or not.

My usage typically involves:

```
Eclipse with the GAE Java plug-ins.
Open Office
Firefox
python
bash / gnome
Nautilus within Ubuntu
Nautilus browsing over to a physical disk that has Windows 7 installed
```

I was asked what is seen when I try to shutdown.  The answer is just the desktop wallpaper with no messages.

Comment: why don't you try poweroff or halt from terminal and see what error is returned?

Comment: There is no error to powering off.

Comment: @brolyan - Can you use CTRL-ALT-F3 to login to a terminal session with your usual login and password, then run sudo kill -sigterm $(pidof X) ?

Comment: I recommend trying to reproduce this error. Try shutting down after running nothing, running Eclipse, running OO, FF, Python, Nautilus, and Nautilus over your Windows 7 disk. Add in there anything else. It might help to make a table for your data. Seems primitive, but you will at least know what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Ubuntu Maverick 10.10 appears to be the only solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

To help with this we are going to have to know what happens when you try and shut down.

I am assuming that it gives you the Ubuntu logo and goes no further?

Then we need to see what it's actually doing.

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the Ubuntu logo should make the logo vanish and the console appear.  That should tell you *why* it's not shutting down (or what it's waiting on), and if you tell us what it's saying we can help you get round the problem.

Comment: Nothing happens when I try to shutdown.  I just see the desktop with my chosen wallpaper - not an ubuntu logo.  The desktop is empty, of course, because I close all the apps that I know about before trying to shutdown.